# How to take an accurate outline (ONLY) of an image PSD

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I would like a technique on how to take only the outline of an image. This image is of a car and would need to be accurate.

I am using Photoshop however do have Illustrator if that program is more useful.

So far I have attempted using this article: [How to Trace an Image Using Photoshop](http://www.wikihow.com/Trace-an-Image-Using-Photoshop)

It was a great read, however my image is of a picture filled with content. The picture attached shows the car with a background. I have to find an efficient method of removing the background and taking a very precise outline of the car.

Attached is the image I am attempting to edit from, and an example of what I want to achieve (example has a little too much detail).

[image]

[*Large image size*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3PgS.jpg)

[image: picture for editing]

Comment: Hi Happy Guy, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Could you please show us what you've tried? It's always good to show a little effort, and it increases your chances of getting a good answer greatly. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Could you please post a example of what you are trying to do and of the image.

Comment: We are all very visual people; it's why we are here.  As @ZachariaSamuelGrierson said, an image or two would really help.

Comment: You would typically either use the auto-trace feature in your vector illustration tool (Illustrator) or you'd trace it by hand in Illustrator.

Comment: Looks like you lost access to your unregisted account. To merge your accounts, go [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/contact#) and select the "I need to merge user profiles" option

Answer (score 8):

Most likely not the answer you *want* to hear.....

If you really want precision in the line art you have to do it manually. I've not seen any auto-trace feature anywhere get good, clean, precise line drawings from a color photograph.

Yes, you can try and simplify the photo, remove color, use the `Find Edges` filter in Photoshop, etc. But the end results are never exceptionally precise.

The best method, in my opinion, is to put in the work.

Open or place the photo into Adobe Illustrator. Once there, double-click the layer the photo is on in the `Layers Panel`. Tick the "Template" box. When you do this, you'll notice the "Dim Images" gets checked and set at 50%. You can decrease the opacity if you feel 50% is too much.

[image]

Then add a new layer *above* the photo, grab the **Pen Tool** and manually start tracing out blocks of the image....

[image]

When your done blocking things out, you can then turn off the visibility for the template layer with the photo on it and refine, add color or fills, etc. as needed to your paths.

This gives *you* control over the amount of detail you want and the precision of the final line art is entirely in your hands.

Comment: Also wanted to add this is actually much less work than it seems. it does not really take all that long to do a decent trace by hand if the complexity is manageable.